# What's wrong with the Recycle Bin (-1)

Tags: sharepoint-online, recycle-bin, count

Why does the Recycle bin show -1 as its count?? This is causing much confusion from users, is this a bug? This particular bin contains 20+ documents but the count is obviously off.

[image]

Comment: Is this showing for all the sites or any specific site has this problem?  What does it show when you open it for both End user and site collection recycle bin?

Comment: i haven't seen this issue, it is very strange. Maybe you can delete an item then check if the number is changed.Anyway, for this issue, I suggest you open a service request in Admin Center->Support.

Comment: I've seen this on multiple site collections. Restoring and Deleting items does not change the count

Answer (score 0):

This is very weird and I think something is broken . I have personally never seen this , let me rephrase , never even heard of it before.

Anyways if there are a lot of items , you can use this PowerShell meanwhile .

Use the script below to determine the recycle bin count .

```
Install-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline


Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com


(Get-PnPRecycleBinItem -FirstStage).count


(Get-PnPRecycleBinItem -firststage | ? ItemType -like "File").count
```

If you want the UI to work , you might need to create a support ticket . That is my only guess right now !!

Comment: With this script I can an error "A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'firstStage'."

Comment: Can you get me a snip of the error please , because the syntax is correct . Reference link - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnprecyclebinitem?view=sharepoint-ps